# ParametricNDSolve with Event

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions, event-detection

Using ParametricNDSolve

```
sol= ParametricNDSolve[{x''[t] + 2 d x'[t] +  x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1,x'[0] ==0,
WhenEvent[ x'[t] == 0.,tEvent = t; "StopIntegration" ,"DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"]}, x, {t, 0, 10}, {d }]
```

I can evaluate the solution for special numerical parametervalues d

```
x[.3] /. sol
(* InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 3.29328}}, <>] *)
```

as expected.

```
tEvent
(* 3.29328*)
```

changes value accordingly.

Obviously the eventtime tEvent depends on the parameter d.

My question:

How can I get directly the dependency `tEvent[d]` for further calculations (for example `Plot[tEvent[d],{d,0,2}]`  or `NMinimize[tEvent[d],d]`? 
Thanks!

Comment: You can use  Plot[Evaluate@tEvent, {d, 0, 2}].

Comment: Thanks, but in your approach the solution sol isn't involved???

Comment: ParametricNDSolve solve the ode, sol and  tEvent  depent on the parameter d. I want to plot tEvent depending on d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

It seems that the ODE solver does some caching, so that the event doesn't fire the second time a parameter is used. If the event never fires, than `tEvent` never gets properly set. So, a better approach might be:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {
    x''[t]+2 d x'[t]+x[t]==0, x[0]==1, x'[0]==0,
    WhenEvent[x'[t]==0., "StopIntegration", "DetectionMethod"->"Interpolation"]
    },
    x,
    {t,0,10},
    {d}
];
```

Since the interpolating function contains the domain, we can use Indexed as follows to create your `tEvent` function:

```
tEvent[d_] := Indexed[sol[d]["Domain"], {1, 2}]
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[tEvent[d], {d, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

**Original answer**

Include `tEvent` as an output:

```
Clear[tEvent];
{xsol, tsol} = {x, tEvent} /. ParametricNDSolve[
    {
    x''[t]+2 d x'[t]+x[t]==0,x[0]==1,x'[0]==0,
    WhenEvent[x'[t]==0., tEvent=t;"StopIntegration","DetectionMethod"->"Interpolation"]
    },
    {x, tEvent},
    {t,0,10},
    {d}
];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[tsol[d], {d, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: What a tricky and easy solution, thank you! If I try to create a list `Table[{xsol[d], tsol[d]}, {d, {0., .5, .7}}]` only the first execution evaluates correct. Rerunning the Table-command tsol[d] stays constant. I have no idea why...

Comment: Sorry I didn't address my feedback to you for the tricky approach. What do you think about my problems repeating the Table-command? Thanks.